# C#, WPF, Having trouble opening a new window

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I've looked through the list of similar questions for this topic and couldn't find any examples which deal with my particular problem.

I'd like to start with the disclaimer that I'm not far off an absolute beginner.

Opening up a window in WPF is quite easy, I've done it before in a previous project and it worked fine.

However, I am struggling to do it again in this new project (login form). I have two classes, MainWindow and CreateAccount.

MainWindow has the event trigger for opening up the CreateAccount window.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

      var account = new CreateAccount(); 
        account.Show();
        this.Close(); 
    }
```

Researching how to open up a new window in WPF gave me snippets very much like this one.

What I want to happen is for, upon triggering the button event, the window I've designed with an account creation form to appear. What instead happens is a blank window pops up with what I can only assume are default dimensions and no border text.

I don't understand how this can be as I specified exactly what I wanted. I don't get any errors either.

The CreateAccount class is mostly just some if statements (I don't want to hunker down with it until I sort out the current issue) and I can't find anything that would cause issue.

Both classes inherit from Window. I took a guess at what might be wrong, thinking 'maybe its an inheritance problem' and so tried to make CreateAccount inherit from MainWindow, but that threw an error which I now understand. Right now I'm lost as to what the problem is and since I don't know that, I can't find out the solution.

Is there anything wrong with the code? Someone suggested that it might be a DataContext issue, but even after looking that up I'm struggling to understand it.

Thank you.

EDIT: Because a lot of people were asking for more code with CreateAccount.xaml.cs(I thought we were only allowed to post snippets):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Login
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for CreateAccount.xaml
/// </summary>

public partial class CreateAccount : Window
{


    public bool canProceedPass = false;
    public bool canProceedUser = false; 
    public void MakeAccount()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void CheckTextInput()
    {
        if (NewUsername.Text != null && NewPassword.Text != null) {

            canProceedUser = true; 
        }
        else
        {
            canProceedUser = false;
            MessageBox.Show("You haven't filled out all the required  fields.");

        }

    }

    public void CheckPassInput()
    {
        if (NewPassword.Text == ConfirmNewPassword.Text)
        {

            canProceedPass = true;

        }else
        {

            return; 

        }

    }

    private void CreateAccountButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (canProceedUser == true && canProceedPass == true)
        { 

            //Add username and password to my SqlDb. 

        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is CreateAccount class? Is is a window? Can you post the code for CreateAccount

Comment: Definitely need to see more of createaccount. I just created a sample app doing exactly as yours and it worked fine. I'm not sure about closing the mainwindow as a strategy and I would also recommend using MVVM if you are not already - although it will increase the learning curve to begin with.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think I could post the entire class! I've edited my post. Sorry!

Comment: `CreateAccount()` should be the name of the constructor, in your code its `MakeAccount()` , and remove the void

Comment: Renamed it, thank you very much for the advice. It hasn't resolved this issue but now I know something for the future.

Comment: did you remove the void like decoherence advised?

Comment: It says it needs a return type. Just googled constructor examples and none of them have return types so I've f'ed up here maybe?

Comment: A constructor needs to be the same name as the class name like class Foo { public Foo() { } } check the case matches too

Comment: @user3752329 it only says that if your constructor name does not match your class name

Comment: Guys I really don't think its a constructor, it's behaving like a regular ol' method. I made it match the class name and it gave me the error: Error 1 'CreateAccount': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

Comment: @user3752329 does your window have an xaml file to it? or did you just create class and inherited Window?

Comment: I would delete this and in visual studio, add new window and call it CreateAccount (I would personally call it CreateAccountView)

Comment: It has an xaml file as well. It itself is a xaml.cs. But it has a xaml file, yes.

Comment: @user3752329 check the x:Class attribute for the Window tag in your xaml, see if the last part of it matches the class name, or even better give us the value of your x:Class atrribute in the xaml for that windw

Comment: Yeah it does :/  <Window x:Name="AccountWindow" x:Class="Login.CreateAccount"

Comment: If you don't want to delete this class, why not create a createaccount2 window and get it working then phase the other one out.

Comment: Yeah, I'll see if the code works in another class.

Comment: Made a new window with a new xaml and cs, it works! Best guess as to why was that my other one didn't have a proper constructor. Thank you all for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A constructor should have the same name as your Class with no return type, in your example the constructor should be:

```
public CreateAccount()
{
   InitializeComponent();
}
```